# How can I scroll my horizontally scrollable table to a certain position by click on data attribute?

Tags: jquery, function, html-table, custom-data-attribute, vertical-scrolling

By click on a certrain date on the left side (for example `2018-04-03`) I wish that my table is scrolling to that positon (in that case `Apr 03`). My approach is not working out. This means, only when I click on "Project 1" my table is scrolling to a position.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".main-table").clone(true).appendTo('#table-scroll').addClass('clone');
});

 var side_width = $( ".fixed-side" ).width()+262;


$("body").on("click", function(e) {
  // the coordinate you clicked
  var x = e.clientX
  var y = e.clientY
  
  // all th.fixed-side in cloned table (include thead and tbody)
  var fixedSide = $('table.clone th.fixed-side')

  // calculate the height of cloned table's tbody
  // var tableHeight = fixedSide.get(0).offsetHeight * fixedSide.length - 1;

  // only first th in tbody
  var tableHeight = fixedSide.get(0).offsetHeight;

  // th's width
  var offsetWidth = fixedSide.get(0).offsetWidth;

  // calculate offsetTop and offsetLeft from body
  var offset = getOffset(fixedSide.get(0))
  
  // skip thead's th
  offset.Top += fixedSide.get(0).offsetHeight;

  // check if click inside the range
  var inRange = (x >= offset.Left && x <= offset.Left + offsetWidth) &&
    (y >= offset.Top && y <= offset.Top + tableHeight)

  if (inRange) {
       var date = $(e.target).closest('tr').find("[data-date]").data("date");
        var result = $('[data-date="'+date+'"]').offset().left;
        $('.table-wrap').scrollLeft(result - side_width); 
       alert("successfull scrolled to "+date);
  }
});

function getOffset(element) {
  var offsetTop = 0;
  var offsetLeft = 0;
  do {
    offsetTop += element.offsetTop;
    offsetLeft += element.offsetLeft;
  } while (element = element.offsetParent);
  var offset = {
    Left: offsetLeft,
    Top: offsetTop,
  }
  return offset;
}
```

```css
.table-scroll {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.table-scroll table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table-scroll th,
.table-scroll td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.clone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.clone th,
.clone td {
  visibility: hidden
}

.clone td,
.clone th {
  border-color: transparent
}

.clone tbody th {
  visibility: visible;
}

.clone .fixed-side {
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  border: none;
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.clone thead,
.clone tfoot {
  background: transparent;
}

.gantt-h {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #b0b0b0;
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.last {
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.gantt td {
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.today {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.fixed-side{
cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
  <div class="table-wrap">
    <table class="main-table table gantt">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" scope="col" class="left-h" style="border-bottom:2px solid #f4f4f4;color:#b0b0b0">Task</th>

          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h" style="font-weight:normal;color:#b0b0b0;">30 Mar</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">31 Mar</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">01 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">02 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">03 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">04 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">05 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">06 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">07 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">08 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">09 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">10 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">11 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">12 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">13 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">14 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">15 Apr</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th data-name="Projekt 1" class="fixed-side project"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> Projekt 1</th>

             <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-03-30"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-03-31"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-01"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-02"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-03"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-04"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-05"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-06"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-07"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-08"></td>
           <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-09"></td>
         <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-10"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-11"></td>
           <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-12"></td>
           <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-13"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-14"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th data-date="2018-04-02" class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> 2018-04-02</th>
           <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-03-30"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-03-31"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-01"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-02"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-03"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-04"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-05"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-06"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-07"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-08"></td>
           <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-09"></td>
         <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-10"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-11"></td>
           <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-12"></td>
           <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-13"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-14"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th data-date="2018-04-03" class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> 2018-04-03</th>

          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-03-30"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-03-31"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-01"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-02"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-03"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-04"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-05"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-06"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-07"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-08"></td>
           <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-09"></td>
         <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-10"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-11"></td>
           <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-12"></td>
           <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-13"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-14"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th data-date="2018-04-01" class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> 2018-04-01</th>
 <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-03-30"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-03-31"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-01"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-02"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-03"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-04"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-05"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-06"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-07"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-08"></td>
           <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-09"></td>
         <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-10"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-11"></td>
           <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-12"></td>
           <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-13"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-14"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th data-date="2018-04-04" class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> 2018-04-04</th>
 <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-03-30"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-03-31"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-01"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-02"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-03"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-04"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-05"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-06"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-07"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-08"></td>
           <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-09"></td>
         <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-10"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-11"></td>
           <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-12"></td>
           <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-13"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-14"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th data-date="2018-04-02" class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> 2018-04-02</th>
         <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-03-30"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-03-31"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-01"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-02"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-03"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-04"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-05"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-06"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-07"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-08"></td>
           <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-09"></td>
         <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-10"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-11"></td>
           <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-12"></td>
           <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-13"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-14"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-15"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if each table is brought in order, you might want to create your data-row attribute to index based on incremental value so that way each row would use the same date and then can scroll to that exact data-row

Comment: @Keith: I would need to use this `$('.table-wrap').scrollLeft(result - side_width); ` outside of the function. I think this is causing the conflict...

Comment: why do you need 2 different tables?

Comment: @Keith Does vertical scroll work with fixed left side with only one table?

Comment: i guess that leads to next question, currently this table only can scroll left to right, when and why would you need to scroll vertically?

Comment: @Keith oh, I mixed the words. I actually meant horizontally :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var tableHeight` is the issue. You have set it to the height of only the first `th` in `tbody` and that is exactly where your intended functionality is working i.e. Projekt 1. (Seems like you missed updating it since you have duly put a comment on top of it stating the same).

Because of that, your clicks are not being evaluated to being `inRange`. You can confirm that by changing

```
var inRange = (x >= offset.Left && x <= offset.Left + offsetWidth) &&
    (y >= offset.Top && y <= offset.Top + tableHeight);`
```

to

```
var inRange = (x >= offset.Left && x <= offset.Left + offsetWidth) &&
    (y >= offset.Top);
```

Hope this helps and you can adjust `tableHeight` to your requirements from here. Also, suggestion by @Keith is spot on.

EDIT:

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb68s0gt/2/). Clicks on dates in left column are being evaluated to be in `inRange` with above suggestion. Horizontal scroll also seems to be working (you can click on 04-04-2018 and then click on 02-04-2018 to confirm that).

Comment: Tested it with my code, but couldn't find a way to result yet

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all that javascript, just shrink it down to this:

https://jsfiddle.net/hgbL1h2y/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".main-table").clone(true).insertBefore('.main-table').addClass('clone');
});

$(".gantt tbody th, .fixed-side").on("click", function(e) {
  var row_num = parseInt( $(this).parent().index() ) + 1;
  var getWidth = $('.gantt td').outerWidth();
  $('.table-wrap').scrollLeft(0 + (getWidth * row_num));    
});

setTimeout(function (){
    $('.clone').find('tr td').remove();
}, 500)
```

Also changed some css:

```
.clone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  position: fixed;
}
.gantt .fixed-side {
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  border: none;
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}
.clone tbody th{
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  border: none;
}
```

and added a margin:

```
<table class="main-table table gantt" style="margin-left: -10px;">
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".main-table").clone(true).insertBefore('.main-table').addClass('clone');
});

$(".gantt tbody th, .fixed-side").on("click", function(e) {
  var row_num = parseInt( $(this).parent().index() ) + 1;
  var getWidth = $('.gantt td').outerWidth();
  $('.table-wrap').scrollLeft(0 + (getWidth * row_num));    
});

setTimeout(function (){
    $('.clone').find('tr td').remove();
}, 500)
```

```css
.table-scroll {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.table-scroll table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table-scroll th,
.table-scroll td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.clone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  position: fixed;
}

.gantt .fixed-side {
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  border: none;
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.clone th,
.clone td {
  visibility: hidden
}

.clone td,
.clone th {
  border-color: transparent
}

.clone tbody th{
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  border: none;
}

.clone .fixed-side {
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  border: none;
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.clone thead,
.clone tfoot {
  background: transparent;
}

.gantt-h {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #b0b0b0;
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.last {
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.gantt td {
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.today {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.fixed-side{
cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
  <div class="table-wrap">
   <table class="main-table table gantt" style="margin-left: -10px;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" scope="col" class="left-h" style="border-bottom:2px solid #f4f4f4;color:#b0b0b0">Task</th>

          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h" style="font-weight:normal;color:#b0b0b0;">30 Mar</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">31 Mar</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">01 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">02 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">03 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">04 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">05 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">06 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">07 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">08 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">09 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">10 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">11 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">12 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">13 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">14 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">15 Apr</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th data-name="Projekt 1" class="fixed-side project"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> Projekt 1</th>

             <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-03-30"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-03-31"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-01"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-02"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-03"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-04"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-05"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-06"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-07"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-08"></td>
           <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-09"></td>
         <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-10"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-11"></td>
           <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-12"></td>
           <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-13"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-14"></td>
          <td data-row="1" data-date="2018-04-15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th data-date="2018-04-02" class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> 2018-04-02</th>
           <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-03-30"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-03-31"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-01"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-02"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-03"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-04"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-05"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-06"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-07"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-08"></td>
           <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-09"></td>
         <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-10"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-11"></td>
           <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-12"></td>
           <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-13"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-14"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th data-date="2018-04-03" class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> 2018-04-03</th>

          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-03-30"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-03-31"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-01"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-02"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-03"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-04"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-05"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-06"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-07"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-08"></td>
           <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-09"></td>
         <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-10"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-11"></td>
           <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-12"></td>
           <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-13"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-14"></td>
          <td data-row="3" data-date="2018-04-15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th data-date="2018-04-01" class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> 2018-04-01</th>
 <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-03-30"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-03-31"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-01"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-02"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-03"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-04"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-05"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-06"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-07"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-08"></td>
           <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-09"></td>
         <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-10"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-11"></td>
           <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-12"></td>
           <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-13"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-14"></td>
          <td data-row="4" data-date="2018-04-15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th data-date="2018-04-04" class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> 2018-04-04</th>
 <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-03-30"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-03-31"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-01"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-02"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-03"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-04"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-05"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-06"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-07"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-08"></td>
           <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-09"></td>
         <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-10"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-11"></td>
           <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-12"></td>
           <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-13"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-14"></td>
          <td data-row="5" data-date="2018-04-15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th data-date="2018-04-02" class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> 2018-04-02</th>
         <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-03-30"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-03-31"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-01"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-02"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-03"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-04"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-05"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-06"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-07"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-08"></td>
           <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-09"></td>
         <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-10"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-11"></td>
           <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-12"></td>
           <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-13"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-14"></td>
          <td data-row="6" data-date="2018-04-15"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, one issue: The dates are not showing the correct dates in your fiddle. If I click for example on "2018-04-03" then it should scroll to "Apr 03"

Comment: Other issue is, that I can not scroll left or right manually by hand anymore

Comment: oh i see, i thought those were random dates and it was just doing it in order, I can fix that. As for hand scrolling, im not having an issue with it. What browser are you in?

Comment: I have firefox. Can you try it with the editor from stackoverflow like I did in the question?

Comment: it might just be a stackoverflow thing, the jfiddle works fine

Comment: is this going to go month by month or is this a full calendar

Comment: This is a full calendar

Comment: I created a snippet in your question with your suggested updates. Can you check it?

Comment: The reason is because the clone is on top of the grid, which is covering the scrolling. If you get rid of the <thead> in the clone table you can scroll.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169240/discussion-between-keith-and-jarla).